# How can I create a matrix in which the user inputs both rows and columns and then enters the values for each position in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, input, row, multiple-columns

This should be how the code works:

```
    n = int(input()) #number of rows, for example 3
    m = int(input()) #number of columns, for example 5
```

Then the user is going to enter a value for a row followed by a value for column.

```
    x = int(input()) #This should be the row number, for example row 1
    y = float(input()) #This should be the value for each position inside of each x.
```

Both x and y need to follow certain conditions so I have them apart. In theory it should look something like this:

```
    matrix = [ [0.4], [0.3, 0.2, 0.5], [0.7] ] #Row 1 has 1 float, Row 2 has 3 float and Row 3 only 1
```

Some floats are going to enter on different rows, like row 1 can have three floats from the input, and another row (row 3) could have 5 floats from the input.

I have tried using the following loop:

```
    for i in range(n): #I have tried multiple ways using len function, append function, etc.
        for j in range(m):
```

But I can't seem to be able to assign each value on the matrix as I have to make sure that the inputs follow certain conditions as the program should read as many different floats as te variable "m" goes.

The reason why I am elaborating the code this way is because I have to calculate an average (in a different function) based on the different values that I get from the float input, making them go through a formula that I already had done before.

Comment: If the user has to enter `m`, the number of colums, at the start, how can it be possible that some rows have more columns? Should `m` only be a maximum number of columns per row?

Comment: Hey @He3lixxx , thanks for your reply! In this case `m` turns to be the amount of `y` inputs the user is going to enter. So if `m = 5` then there are going to be 5 different `y` inputs each assigned to a row number determined by the `n` amount. I guess that maybe the other positions on each column would be be 0.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this should be roughly what you need:

```py
row_input_count = int(input("please enter the number of rows you want to input: "))
column_count = int(input("please enter the number of columns: "))

matrix = []
for _ in range(row_input_count):
    row_index = -1
    while row_index < 0:
        row_index = int(input(f"please select a row: "))

    matrix = matrix + [[0] * column_count] * (row_index + 1 - len(matrix))

    values = [0] * (column_count + 1)
    while len(values) > column_count:
        value_string = input(f"please input up to {column_count} values for row {row_index}: ")
        values = [float(x) for x in value_string.split()]
    values = values + [0] * (column_count - len(values))
    matrix[row_index] = values

print("The resulting matrix: [")
for row in matrix:
    print(row)

print("]")
```

Does this help you understand how the parts you already figured out could work together? I think it should be all relatively easy to read. Python's syntax for repeating elements in a list might be a bit strange to get used to:

```py
>>> ["hi"] * 3
['hi', 'hi', 'hi']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @He3lixxx I'll combine it with what I have and see if it works. I mean it should, just by trying it out it outputs the matrix. Now I need to adapt it as the inputs come in same lines and need to have certain conditions. Thanks again for your help!